# clang-format ignore `**` when auto-formatting

Tags: c++, clang-format, autoformatting

In our department we are using a simplified implementation of C++ for our engineers to code their calculations, which is then translated to C++ before compilation.
To bring the whole code base, C++ and the simplified implementation, to the same style, we want to make use of a formatter, preferably **clang-format**. Unluckily one simplification won't work with clang-format:

- Pointers and references cannot be defined using `*` or `&`
- Instead powers are written using double asterisks `**`, f.i. `a = 5**2` instead of `a = pow(5, 2)`

As a consequence, clang-format interprets `**` as a "pointer to a pointer" and applies formatting, which is breaking the equation.

### question

Is there any way in clang-format to either:

- deactivate formatting of pointers **entirely** (I tried all pointer style options, but probably missed the correct option)
- *or* (preferably) treat `**` as a math operator only
- *or* exclude/ignore `**` formatting by a regex-include such as in Pylint (haven't found an option for this)

A method of last resort could also include using other tools such as uncrustify, but I'd *really* like to **avoid** this.

Comment: Please don't try to describe what you want, show an example, an actual formatting result and a desired result.

Comment: I'm currently on christmas holidays and just wanted to ask for help with something I still had on my mind. Unluckily I won't be able to provide an example before January 8th. But I'll add more details as soon as possible. :)

Comment: Can you forbid some other operator (_e.g._, something weird like `->*`) in your dialect?

Comment: Yep, asterisks `*` will **only** be used for **math** in the dialect.

Comment: In line with what I'm guessing @DavisHerring is thinking about, is the ^ (xor) allowed in your dialect? Its use is uncommon in a lot of code and its C++ syntax is closer to your FORTRANish **. The idea is 1) search and replace ** with something that will format as desired in dialect code; 2) reformat dialect code; 3) search and replace back to ** from whatever.

Comment: Ah yeah, got it now, thanks for the explanation. This sounds like a very good workaround, if there is no such setting in clang-format. `->*` is in fact not supported by the dialect (as of now). Any other uncommon operators I could use as a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of course guessed in the comments, my suggestion is to temporarily replace the `**` operator with another for the duration of the formatting.  This requires that the target operator be otherwise unused, of course: **escaping** doesn’t work very well when you need a parser to understand the result.  Ideally, it should be nearly the same lexical **length** to avoid bad formatting after restoring the original.

It also helps if the replacement has nearly the same **precedence** as the real operator.  That hasn’t been specified here, but it surely has at least that of multiplication.

All of these considerations suggest **`->*`**: it’s already a rare operator, has a precedence only one away from `*`, `/`, and `%`, and is either one character longer or shorter depending on whitespace preferences.

Comment: Many thanks for the details, especially on precedence! I'll accept the answer when no one comes up with a clang-format built-in solution.